# Oracle update with subquery - performanceissue

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update, exists, database-performance

I'm having some trouble with an update statement in my oracle database.
The query takes to much time and the temp tablespace is running out of space, but it provides the correct data.

I tried to convert the subqueries to joins but i couldn't figure out how to do it correctly. 
If someone knows how to improve the statement or how to convert it into a join i would be really grateful.

```
        UPDATE table1 t1
        SET t1.inxdc = (SELECT sda_x
           FROM table2 t2
           WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1
             AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
             AND t1.c3 = t2.c3
             AND t1.c4 = t2.c4
             AND t1.c5 = t2.c5
             AND t1.c6 = t2.c6
             AND t2.ident = 'K_SDA_W'
             AND rownum=1)
      WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
           FROM table2 t2
           WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1
             AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
             AND t1.c3 = t2.c3
             AND t1.c4 = t2.c4
             AND t1.c5 = t2.c5
             AND t1.c6 = t2.c6
             AND t2.ident = 'K_SDA_W');
```

edit1:
Some information for the tables

- table1 PKs = c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6
- table2 PKs = ident,c4,c5,c6, and 3 others not mentioned in the statement (c7,c8,c9)
- index: besides the PKs only on table2 c1
- table1 data: 12466 rows
- table2 data: 194827 rows

edit2:
Execution Plan

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                     | Name                 |
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT              |                      |
    |   1 |  UPDATE                       | table1               |
    |   2 |   NESTED LOOPS SEMI           |                      |
    |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL          | table1               |
    |   4 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| table2               |
    |   5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | t2.c1                |
    |   6 |   COUNT STOPKEY               |                      |
    |   7 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| table2               |
    |   8 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | t2.PK                |
    --------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Which is bigger T1 or T2? what is the PK for T1 and T2? Any indexes?

Comment: How big are your tables, and how long does it take to run this update? Can you show us the execution plan? Does the subquery use some index? How long does it take to retrieve a value from the subquery for one related row in `table1`?

Comment: Why rownum = 1? Is there duplicates in T2? Does it mean T2 > T1 in size? What is plan saying!!

Answer (score 0):

There are very few rows in `Table1`, just drop the `WHERE` clause in this particular situation and add `NVL` to the value returned from subquery:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
        SET t1.inxdc = NVL((SELECT sda_x
           FROM table2 t2
           WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1
             AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
             AND t1.c3 = t2.c3
             AND t1.c4 = t2.c4
             AND t1.c5 = t2.c5
             AND t1.c6 = t2.c6
             AND t2.ident = 'K_SDA_W'
             AND rownum=1), t1.inxdc);
```

In general your update should be quick, have you checked performance of the subquery? Check if an index (and which one) is used on `table2` for the subquery (best, show us the exection plan).

Answer (score 0):

I think table t2 shoulkd have an index on c1,c2,c3, c4,c5,c6,ident
In this case the update of t1 should be really faster.